# Collect Multiple JSONP Results

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp

I have a javascript application that gets data from multiple jsonp requests. Once all of the data is returned the page will be updated with the new data. Below is pseudocode, but it's structured for a synchronous environment.

```
function GetAllData() {

   var data1= GetData1();
   var data2= GetData2();
   var data3= GetData3();

   UpdatePage(data1,data2,data3);
}
```

The issue I have is that I need to collect, and know, when all the data has been returned from the jsonp requests before I update the page. I was looking at jquery deferred, but I'm not sure if that's the correct solution.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) is your correct solution, when you are using JQuery.

```
function GetData1() {
    return $.ajax("/foo", ...);
}

function GetData2() {
    return $.ajax("/bar", ...);
}

function GetData3() {
    return $.ajax("/baz", ...);
}

function UpdatePage(data1, data2, data3) {
    ...
}

function Error() {
    alert("An error occurred while fetching data");
}

function GetAllData() {
    $.when(GetData1(), GetData2(), GetData3()).then(UpdatePage, Error);
}
```